# JavaFx on Apple Silicon / UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: libprism_es2.dylib

Tags: javafx, apple-silicon

I'm trying to build a JavaFx project using Maven, gradle, sbt, or similar on a MacOS system with an Apple Silicon chip, and I've encountered an error something like this:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: libprism_es2.dylib
```

What to do?

Answer (score 9):

[JavaFx does support Apple Silicon (aarch64) architecture starting from version 17-ea+8](https://gluonhq.com/javafx-for-apple-m1/).

But you need to qualify the dependency with a classifier for the operating system *and the architecture*.

With Maven, the dependency should look something like this:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
  <version>18.0.2</version>
  <classifier>mac-aarch64</classifier>
</dependency>
<!-- ... -->
```

In gradle, the [JavaFx Plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.openjfx.javafxplugin) version 0.0.11 or later will append the correct classifier:

```kotlin
plugins {
    // ...
    id( "org.openjfx.javafxplugin" ) version "0.0.13"
    // ...
}
```

In sbt, you would add the following to your `build.sbt` file:

```scala
lazy val myproject = ( project in file( "." ) )
  .settings(
    // ...
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      //...
      "org.openjfx" % "javafx-controls" % "18.0.2" classifier "mac-aarch64",
      //...
    )
    // ...
  )
```

With each of these build tools, you can do sophisticated stuff so that your build definition dynamically resolves which classifier to apply, regardless of the platform you're building for. But that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Note that although `System.getProperty( "os.name" )` does ***not*** resolve to the exact text that **org.openjfx** uses to identify the target platform in its classifiers, `System.getProperty( "os.arch" )` does resolve to the text `aarch64` on an Apple Silicon computer.

Comment: In my case, I am using VS Code and Maven. I just need to change the version code to 18.0.2 (<version>18.0.2</version>); classifier is not required to be specified.